# Unable to convert from Julian INT date to regular TSQL Datetime

Tags: t-sql, julian-date

Help me Stackoverflow, I'm close to going all "HULK SMASH" on my keyboard over this issue. I have researched carefully but I'm obviously not getting something right.

I am working with a Julian dates referenced from a proprietary tool (Platinum SQL?), though I'm working in SQL 2005. I can convert their "special" version of Julian into datetime when I run a select statement. Unfortunately it will not insert into a datetime column, I get the following error when I try:

The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

So I can't setup datetime criteria for running a report off of the Stored Procedure.

Original Value: 733416
Equivalent Calendar Value: 01-09-2009

Below is my code... I'm so close but I can't quite see what's wrong, I need my convert statement to actually convert the Julian value (733416) into a compatible TSQL DATETIME value.

```
SELECT       
org_id, 
CASE WHEN date_applied = 0 THEN '00-00-00' 
ELSE convert(char(50),dateadd(day,date_applied-729960,convert(datetime, '07-25-99')),101) 
END AS date_applied,

CASE WHEN date_posted = 0 THEN '00-00-00'  
ELSE convert(char(50),dateadd(day,date_posted-729960,convert(datetime, '07-25-99')),101) 
END AS date_posted

from general_vw
```

Comment: Pretty sure my answer fixes your problem. If it does please mark it as the accepted answer, otherwise please let me know how my answer doesn't quite help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT       
org_id, 
CASE WHEN date_applied = 0 OR date_applied < 639906 THEN convert(datetime, '1753-01-01')
ELSE dateadd(day,date_applied-729960,convert(datetime, '07-25-99'))
END AS date_applied,

CASE WHEN date_posted = 0 OR date_applied < 639906 THEN convert(datetime, '1753-01-01')
ELSE dateadd(day,date_posted-729960,convert(datetime, '07-25-99'))
END AS date_posted

from general_vw
```

You're casting to char but want a datetime so that's one easy fix.

You were also using '00-00-00' as your minimum date, but the minimum TSQL date is '1753-01-01'. Alternatively you could use something like ('1900-01-01') but that would need a change to the "less than" date_applied comparer.

I've added a "less than" date_applied comparer too. I calculated this as "SELECT 729960 + datediff(day,convert(datetime, '07-25-99'), convert(datetime,'1753-01-01'))". Any number less than this would cause a date underflow.

Comment: No problem, I added a date_applied comprarer in case date_applied is ever less than a number that would cause a date underflow but that's probably a non-issue for your dataset.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had figured out the whole casting to datetime instead of char, but the minimum date was holding me back. You truly saved my bacon tonight!!